# Mixture of ADO.NET and Entity Framework Transactions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, transactions, transactionscope

We need a bit of help, we have been trying to manage this and it simply isn't working.  Basically we have a site that uses entity framework and ADO.NET as a mixture, we do this as some selects would simply not work with the way we are getting data using a publishing structure and on some saves using entity framework would be impossible or take minutes to save with the volume of data selected and manipulated.

At the beginning of a request we have a connection provider which tries to manage the connection and either provides a standalone SqlConnection for ado.net reads or a single connection object which is used with EF and any ado.net sprocs that may do updates, we can then call save changes which commits the transaction scope.

Unfortunately this simply isn't working, we would like to avoid escalation to MSDTC but if there is no other way we will live with it.  The question is should we at the start of the request create a single sqlconnection and share it with everything or should we just create a SqlConnection object for everything independently and use transaction scope and let it do what it needs to even if we get escalated to MSDTC.

Some of the errors we are seeing are:

```
- Cannot promote the transaction to a distributed transaction because there is an active save point in this transaction.
- Cannot use SAVE TRANSACTION within a distributed transaction.
- The transaction has aborted.
- The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.
```

We are also getting timeouts where I believe a standalone connection is attempting to select from a table participating in the transaction but using a connection not inside the transaction.

I would appreciate any advice here as what we have tried simply isn't working.

Comment: Connections should have _exactly_ the same connection string and be opened and closed _subsequently_ within one transaction scope for MSDTC not to kick in. They can be created outside the scope.

Comment: We have exactly the same connection string but when we close the first connection and open the second it immediately tries to promote to MSDTC, if we allow it to then we start getting the errors mentioned above.  We tried having a single SqlConnection per request but that causes other errors and I don't like the idea of having one connection and leaving open for the whole request.

Comment: Are the connection string really exactly identical? Even whitespace cannot differ.

Comment: Yes they are, they are all being accessed via a static property looking at the same config file.  I think our problem is that we are mixing entity framework and standard ado.net.  I am tracking all the SqlConnection objects created, when they are disposed and when the connection is open or closed and while when we get the MSDTC error there is only one connection open there are 2 non disposed SqlConnections one of which must be the one being used by the ObjectContext which is created at the beginning of the request and disposed at the end.  Is this what is causing the MSDTC escalation?

Comment: The non-disposed connections are suspect. They may still be open. You can offer a context a connection to work with, which will give you more control. Or, conversely, you can use the context's connection for your ADN.Net stuff. I have a scenario where I do the latter, without MSDTC troubles.